# Overflow-x: hidden also hides y content

Tags: html, css, navigation, overflow

I have a container with some text and an image, and a *navigation div* that should (when the time comes) slide in from the right.

To make this happen, I though I'd push the *div* to the right of the screen and put `overflow-x: hidden` on it's container to hide it, and then push it back into the screen when it's needed.

**The problem is**, when I set `overflow-x: hidden` on the container, it also clips off the vertical content of the navigation.
[Here's a fiddle with a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w23adhbm/).

**What I have tried:**

- Setting different values for `overflow-y`
- placing the *navigation div* in different containers, inside and outside of the content container

None of which seem to work.

I have looked at other questions with a similiar issues, but none solve my problem - they suggest alternative solutions that don't fit my situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from your `.img` class in CSS, where you have `height: 200px;`. The image you're loading is actually 310px tall, and thus you get that the bottom third (approximately) is clipped off.

Comment: The container needs to stay in that height. The navigation, though, should be taller than it.

Comment: When you make the `.nav` have `position: absolute`, you take it out of the flow of the document (essentially saying "draw everything on the page, _then_ place this element"), meaning it can't be used to determine height. The only thing the browser has to determine height is the image, which is 200 px tall, plus the text above it, and thus it clips the element to that size.

Comment: Right, so in theory, I can have the `.nav` in any height I want, regardless of the height of it's container. However that doesn't happen.

Comment: Yes, the nav can be any height, but it's the container that provides the "window" into it, regardless of how its positioned. The `.nav` is still however tall you want it, but because it's still a child of the ~200px-tall container, it still gets clipped. You either need to move it outside of the container, or enlarge the container's height to show the entire `.nav`.

Comment: If I move it outside the container, I won't be able to clip the x axis of it. If I enlarge the container's height, the rest of the page content will also be pushed, while I want the `.nav` to float above it and not interrupt it.

Comment: You can still clip the x-axis of the entire document (the `body` tag), and have the `nav` be a child of that, positioned all the way to the right. That way, it can expand to to its full height without clipping in the y-axis (or, no clipping beyond what the webpage is already being clipped to to fit in the browser window).

Comment: This is really weird. I tried setting `overflow-x: hidden` on the body, and in the fiddle it works perfectly, but when I set it on my actual project it does nothing. Even stranger, I copied over the entire HTML and CSS of my project to JSFiddle and it works great there! But still the overflow has no effect when I open the project on my machine. Do you have any idea about why this is happening?

Comment: I just figured it out: For some reason you need to set the `html` and the `body` to `overflow-x: hidden`, otherwise it won't work. Thanks for all the help! You should probably update your answer to help other people.