# Why is "overflow-x: hidden" also hiding overflow-y?

Tags: css, overflow

EDIT 2: Turns out the problem wasnt with the overflow but had to do with the grid of the grandparent element. My question should have been [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/css-grid-problem-using-1fr-will-make-the-content-extend-itself-too-much/288578). This makes this whole post irrelevant. Sorry for the inconvenience. It won't let me delete the post.

EDIT: [Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjobe/8n9o6dea/latest/) to my codebase because the answers until now are all correct but don't apply. Down below is a super simplified version of my issue.

I have read quite a lot of posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436452/overflow-x-hidden-also-hides-vertical-content-too), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045560/overflow-x-hidden-also-hides-y-content/35045640), [3](https://medium.com/@justicart/overflow-x-scroll-overflow-y-visible-c1a98238e002) ...) about how the two overflows clash with eachother, but nothing has worked for me. Overflow-x & y cannot be used in combination, and I get that. But I am only declaring one...

The paragraph should not be visible outside of the container (left and right). However, setting overflow-x: hidden also hides the title of my box. (I want the title over the border).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```css
main {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 1em;
  outline: 3px solid;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2em;
  left: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

p {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec convallis leo.</p>
</main>
```

Comment: "Setting one axis to visible (the default) while setting the other to a different value results in visible behaving as auto." ([see note in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)) — `auto` is the same as `hidden` but with scrollbars if needed, hence why your content is hidden. Best bet? Add a wrapper for your inner `<main>`'s content (like `<div><p>…</p></div>`) and set your overflow rules on that div.

Answer (score 5):

For me using overflow-x: clip; instead of overflow-x: hidden; took care of it

Answer (score 0):

You title is not displayed because you have position: absolute set to it.
Just remove the position absolute and leave the elements to be displayed in natural order.

Learn more about css positioning on the link below:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Also here is a link that explains how the overflow property works
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp

Comment: If ithis solved your problem, can you sign my answer as answer for this question

Comment: As I mentioned, I want the title over the border just like in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKftB.jpg) example

Comment: if you cant remove position relative from the main tag, then you can try to wrap the main tag in another div so that it becomes a container to the elements inside. you can set that div to position relative and set the inside elements accordingly.
That way the inside elements will be positioned relatively to the wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

> **Why is “overflow-x: hidden” also hiding overflow-y ?**

`overflow-x` and `overflow-y` will compute to `auto` if one is `visible` and the other is `hidden`, `scroll` or `auto`

**Demo**

```css
[test] {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
}

[overflow] {
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 30px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
overflow-y should be visible because that is the default, but no.
<div test>
  Some long text, not really
  <div overflow>vertical overflow</div>
</div>
```

---

Instead of hiding the overflow on the `<main>`container, hide it on the `<p>`

```css
main {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 1em;
  outline: 3px solid;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2em;
  left: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec convallis leo.</p>
</main>
```

Answer (score -1):

- remove `position: relative;` from main.
- remove `left: 5px;` from h4
- change `top: -2em;` to `top: 0em;` in h4

Comment: I need the `position: relative` because otherwise my h4 is relative to the root element, which I don't want..